# How can I launch this PowerShell script in a new hidden window

Tags: powershell

I am working on a Reboot Scheduling application to be used on simple remote machines. It has to be user friendly though so I have to have multiple scripts and tasks in the background. my main GUI script needs to launch a **Secondary Script** in a NEW hidden window so that the **Main GUI Script** can close.

the **Secondary Script (Reboot.ps1)** will run until the machine restarts if the user has a scheduled reboot pending.

The code below starts the **Secondary Script** hidden but as a sort of "child job", since this script can run "forever" it wont end thus leaving the **Main GUI script** frozen open until killed in task manager (not very user friendly I know..)

```
    $program = Powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -file "C:\Reboot.ps1"
    $scriptblock = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock("Invoke-Command {$program}")
    Invoke-Command -NoNewScope -Scriptblock $scriptblock
```

So what I'm asking is if anyone knows how to start the **Secondary Script** in a new PowerShell window, instance, environment, anything that allows the **Main GUI Script** to close. Preferably, less intensive if possible. :) thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)'s own `-WindowStyle Hidden` parameter to launch your script hidden and asynchronously (`Start-Process`'s default):

```
Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden powershell.exe -Args '-File', 'C:\Reboot.ps1'
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks really complicated for what you're trying to achieve, use `Start-Process`

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-windowstyle hidden -file "C:\Reboot.ps1"'
```

Comment: By the time `powershell.exe` sees `-windowstyle hidden`, it has already been launched in a _visible_ console window; use `Start-Process`' own `-WindowStyle` parameter instead.